# Does this PRCD have any differential current transformer inside?

Tags: rcd

Its very important to have portable residual current devices (PRCD) to plug in our electrical equipments in the field, or use anywhere or even in our workplace. I got this china made PRCD from a package. Do you think it has any differential current transformer or in short, sense coil inside? Have you encountered them or similar form factor made in other countries?

[image]

[image]

Comment: most lower-cost electronics you can buy anywhere are made at least in significant parts in china. I don't think RCDs are an exception, so "China-made" is really a distraction here. "Does this RCD contain a sense coil": Don't know, look inside, can't see it from the outside, can you?

Comment: I'm reaching for my X-ray goggles... oops dropped em and broken em.

Comment: It wouldn't be impossible to design something resembling an RCD without using a differential current transformer, so the answer is ... maybe. If you need to know, tear one apart. If yo udon't know what you're looking apart, add photos to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you pop the cover off I would expect to see a typical ASIC and a ZCT transformer. It has the usual test and reset switches and fault indicator lamp.

According to the description of operation in [this](https://item.jd.com/100009113040.html) advertisement, there is a sense transformer inside.

[image]

Which Google translates to (emphasis added):

> When a leakage or electric shock occurs, the **transformer in the leakage protector will immediately generate an induced voltage**, and the internal power will be automatically cut off to prevent electric shock accidents caused by leakage. After the leakage or danger is eliminated, press the reset button to restore normal use

Based on photos of other products from this company, the (~25mm diameter) ZCT is at the output terminal block end and is free-floating inside the polycarbonate housing. Load appears to be a 1K 1% resistor.

Comment: If it has sense coil, then its a real RCD and not the old earth leakage circuit breaker. Is there a similar portable RCD made in other countries like UK? Or is the PRCD only a chinese invention?

Comment: There are [other products](https://www.larsonelectronics.com/images/product/Manual/244109.PDF)  that are like a short extension cord with a GFCI in the middle. But this one is probably safer in that you have to wire it in, so the user can't bypass it as easily.